# Alfresco custom model - not showing in worklow

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to add a text field to the standard adhoc workflow but the field never appears on the screen. I have tried added some other standard bpm: fields to the view and they get displayed but not the custom one.

Is there anything obvious I am missing?

I have cloned the workflow and added the following.

Workflow model:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Definition of new Model -->
<model name="lhwf:workflowmodel"
xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0">

<!-- Optional meta-data about the model -->
<description>Workflow Model</description>
<author>O</author>
<version>1.0</version>

<!-- Imports are required to allow references to definitions in other models -->
<imports>
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0"
        prefix="d" />
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0"
        prefix="bpm" />
    <import uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/workflow/1.0" 
    prefix="wf"/>
</imports>

<!-- Introduction of new namespaces defined by this model -->
<namespaces>
    <namespace uri="http://www.test.com/model/workflow/1.0"
        prefix="lhwf" />
</namespaces>

<types>
    <type name="lhwf:submitMyTask">
        <parent>bpm:startTask</parent>
        <properties>
            <property name="lhwf:actionRequired">
                <type>d:text</type>
                <mandatory>true</mandatory>
                <multiple>false</multiple>
            </property>
        </properties>
    </type>
</types>
</model>
```

The share-config-custom.xml file looks like this

```
<alfresco-config>
   <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="activiti$activitiAdhoc2">
   <forms>
       <form>
           <field-visibility>
               <show id="bpm:workflowDescription" />
               <show id="lhwf:actionRequired" />
               <show id="bpm:workflowDueDate" />
            `  <show id="bpm:workflowPriority" />
               <show id="bpm:assignee" />
               <show id="packageItems" />
               <show id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" />
           </field-visibility>
           <appearance>
               <set id="" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.general" />
               <set id="info" appearance="" template="/org/alfresco/components/form/2-column-set.ftl" />
               <set id="assignee" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.assignee" />
               <set id="items" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.items" />
               <set id="other" appearance="title" label-id="workflow.set.other" />

               <field id="bpm:workflowDescription" label="Title">
                  <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/textarea.ftl">
                 <control-param name="style">width: 95%</control-param>
              </control>
           </field>
           <field id="lhwf:actionRequired" label="Action Required" set="info" />
           <field id="bpm:workflowDueDate" label-id="workflow.field.due" set="info">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/date.ftl">
                     <control-param name="showTime">false</control-param>
                     <control-param name="submitTime">false</control-param>
              </control>
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:workflowPriority" label-id="workflow.field.priority" set="info">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/priority.ftl" />
           </field>
           <field id="bpm:assignee" label-id="workflow.field.assign_to" set="assignee" />
           <field id="packageItems" set="items" />
           <field id="bpm:sendEMailNotifications" set="other">
              <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/workflow/email-notification.ftl" />
           </field>
        </appearance>
     </form>
  </forms>
</config>
```

Thanks in advance
O

Comment: Did you create your own workflow file ? If yes, could you please post it ?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following.

```
<show id="lhwf:actionRequired" force="true"/>
```

Can you please share the bpmn file here?

Comment: Thanks - that did the trick. Why would I need to do a force="true" to get it to display?

Comment: Let me deploy your model + share config file and keep you posted on this.